# What is the angle from (0,0) to (longitude, latitude)?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, spheres, angle

Starting on the crossing between the equator and the Greenwich meridian (0,0),
one can proceed to any point on Earth with a given longitude and latitude along a great circle.

Seen from the centre of the Earth, what is the angle from the point (0,0) to the point (longitude, latitude), along that great circle?

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$ and $L$ be respectively the longitude and the latitude of a certain point on earth.

then Its coordinates will be

$$x=R\cos(L)\cos(l)$$
$$y=R\cos(L)\sin(l)$$
$$z=R\sin(L)$$

$R$ is the Earth radius.
$L=\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives the northern pole with $(0,0,R)$ as coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Translating from spherical to Cartesian.

$x = 4000 \cos\theta\cos \phi\\
y = 4000 \sin\theta\cos \phi\\
z = 4000 \sin \phi$

$\phi$ is degrees latitude.  South is negative degrees latitude.
$\theta$ is degrees longitude.  Lets make East positive, and West negative..

$4000$ is the radius of the earth in miles.  (6,400 km if you prefer, or $r$, it won't really make a difference.)

$\cos \alpha = (\cos\theta\cos \phi, \sin\theta\cos \phi, \sin \phi)\cdot(1,0,0)\\
\alpha = \arccos (\cos\theta\cos\phi)$